# Using a LabJack to control SparkFun's Addressable LED strip

Tags: c++, c, compilation, microcontroller, adafruit

I'm attempting to use a LabJack U3-LV to control an addressable [LED strip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12025). I need the following libraries: `Adafruit_NeoPixel.h`, `u3.h`, `labjackusb.h` (in addition to a few standard libraries).

I have been able to control a single LED successfully with the code below:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "u3.h"
#include "labjackusb.h"

int main() {
  HANDLE hDevice;
  u3CalibrationInfo caliInfo;
  int localID;
  long error;

  localID = -1;
  hDevice = openUSBConnection(localID);
  if (hDevice == NULL) {
    goto done;
    printf("Invalid connection\n");
  }

  eDO(hDevice, 1, 0, 1);

  done:
    return 0;

  close:
    if (error < 0)
      printf("Received an error code of %ld\n", error);
    closeUSBConnection(hDevice);
}
```

I use the following command to compile this code: `` $ gcc lj.c u3.c labjackusb.c -o cff_c `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0` ``

My issues is with the [Adafruit NeoPixel](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel) library. I realize that this library is written in C++, rather than C, and this is completely unfamiliar territory for me. I am looking for guidance on how to include the C++ Adafruit Neopixel library in my C code, or if there is some easier way to interface with the LED strip.

Links to libraries: [U3](https://github.com/labjack/exodriver/tree/master/examples/U3), [labjackusb](https://github.com/labjack/exodriver/tree/master/liblabjackusb), [Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel)

Comment: Do you really need to contaminate such a simple code with `goto`s?

Comment: just setting up for later, it's going to get quite a bit more involved